# C # Struct private/public error

Tags: c#, struct

I am having problems with my Struct :), the compiler gives me the error

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'SonyasProgram.Form1.frameLimits.Max.Y.get'"

I have tried looking for a solution but none par particularly clear. Here is my code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public struct frameLimits
    {
        public struct Max
        {
            private int yval = 220;
            public int Y
            {
                get
                {
                    return yval;
                }
                set
                {
                    yval = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        frameLimits.Max.Y = 1;
```

The last line is where the error is identified. Any help would be awesome, thanks !

Comment: Ask yourself the question... *"Why am I using structs here?"*

Comment: @ChaosPandion has posed a good question. If you want more info see resources like *Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx and *11.3 Class and struct differences* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664471(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

(followed by **Hacked Solution**, followed by **Simplified Solution**)

Currently you have two data types declared and one is nested, so you can declare variables using each of the data types as such:

```
frameLimits.Max highest = new frameLimits.Max();
highest.Y = 5;
```

IntelliSense shows: `highest.`[image]

```
frameLimits limits = new frameLimits();
// no members exist on the frameLimits type, so nothing to access.
```

IntelliSense shows: `limits.`[image]

IntelliSense can help sort it out.

The nested structure isn't usable in the way you originally attempted because as others have already indicated before me, you're trying to use the types instead of instances of those types.

### Hacked Solution

If I add an instance field called MaxValue to your Max struct, then I might be getting close to what you intended.  This will enable the caller code to be:

```
            frameLimits limits = new frameLimits();
            limits.MaxValue.Y = 5;
```

However that's a really convoluted way to do it and not recommended.

Modified struct is this:

```
public struct frameLimits
{
    public struct Max
    {
        private int yval;
        public int Y
        {
            get
            {
                return yval;
            }
            set
            {
                yval = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Max MaxValue;
}
```

### A Simplified Solution

You could remove the inner struct to simply things, however you're still under some restrictions with the struct and that's why I implement the default value of 220 as I did.

The new caller code is:

```
            FrameLimits limits = new FrameLimits();
            Console.Write( limits.MaxY );  // prints 220
            limits.MaxY = 5;
```

This struct is simplified to a degree (removed nested struct):

```
public struct FrameLimits
{
    private int? yval;

    public int MaxY
    {
        get
        {
            return yval.HasValue ? yval.Value : 220;
        }
        set
        {
            yval = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the initialize before use requirement.

Comment: How do i achieve what i am trying to then ? what do i have to use to accomplish it ?

Comment: I added an example of what you might have intended, but it's really a mutilated hack so don't use it.

Comment: I added a second solution to the bottom that still uses a struct but is simplified and keeps the default value of 220 intact.

Answer (score 2):

Just as the compiler is telling you, you're trying to perform an operation that needs a static variable. You either want to create an instance of frameLimits, or more likely, declare `yval` as `static`.

Answer (score 1):

`frameLimits` and `Max` are *types* not `struct` *instances* - you can only set instance properties of an instance. Besides that you should really not use mutable, nested structs - please reconsider.

Comment: What do you suggest then ? I'm used to using records in pascal, and that is what i needed in this situation and a struct was the closest thing i could find.

Comment: @Trent: In most cases classes do just fine instead of structs

Answer (score 0):

frameLimits is a struct (think type), so you need to either create an instance first in order to your assignment, or make the path to the field to only contain static members.